# Is it possible to use the GHC API to modify a program while compiling it?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

I want to test the implementation a compiler optimization by piggybacking into the GHC compilation process and altering its Core representation. The idea would be to have something like:

```
runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
   ...
   c <- compileToCoreModule targetFile
   compileCoreToObj False (modify c)
   ...
```

where `modify` takes the Core representation and returns the modified version. This code, however, fails (even when modify does nothing at all) with the not very helpful message:

```
expectJust mkStubPaths
```

Any ideas on how to make this work, or if it's even possible to implement a code transformation this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds like a bug in `compileCoreToObj` to me.  Please [report it](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug).

Comment: I was hesitant to report it because I wasn't sure if I was using the functions correctly. Are there any examples of these kinds of transformations?

Comment: I don't know of any specific examples, no.

Comment: Is there any progress with this issue? I've tried today exactly the same code and it resulted in the same error message.

Answer (score 6):

GHC has support for [plugins](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/compiler-plugins.html) now, which appear to do exactly what you want.